# SoundManager2 SWF Load Issue

Tags: javascript, flash, code-access-security

Trying to load Soundmanager2's SWF file from our CDN. I assume I'm running into cross domain flash issues. has anybody done this? it is even possible?

here's what I'm trying...

```
var allowxdomainscripting = true;
var xdomain = "*";
soundManager.url = 'http://cdn.mycompany.com/inc/soundmanager2.swf';
```

there's a very obscure reference to this in the documentation, but it's pretty vague...

http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/generated/src/SoundManager2_AS3.html

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where you are using those 2 vars: _allowxdomainscripting_ and _xdomain_ ?

Comment: I assumed soundManger2 was listening for them.. although I just searched inside soundmanger2.min.js for that string and it's not mentioned, so I looked a little closer at the above link and it seems if those two vars are true then this paramater is set "Security.allowDomain(xdomain)".. at that point I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: I thougth that code was ActionScript. Is it JS?

Comment: indeed it is.. calling a Flash file to play sound.

Comment: that is action script 3, i think you need to recompile the .swf file after adding in your extra domains. I am working on something similar, trying to add sound on ebay listings!

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this as well at one point.  SoundManager2 now comes with cross-domain versions of the swf files.

They are zipped up in swf/soundmanager2_flash_xdomain.zip

https://github.com/scottschiller/SoundManager2/tree/master/swf

Simply unzip and replace with the standard .swf files provided with SoundManager2 and your problem should go away.

Comment: I tried this solution but got error aSound: Failed to load?... Is there any issue with SSL? I want to load a cross domain file with SSL so my URL is like "https:test.com/play.php?file=play.wav"

Comment: there's shouldn't be any problems w/ SSL over x-domain.  also, the url example you show is invalid (eg. https:test.com should be https://test.com

Comment: I didn't really understand what was going on with my script but this was the solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

**THANK YOU VERY MUCH!**

I stumbled upon this answer by total chance after wasting a couple of hours trying to get SM2 SWF embed to work.

I'm going to "revive" this to add a few keywords so Google indexes this answer... Maybe the next person trying to embed SoundManager2 SWF in a cross-domain environment gets it done a little quicker than I did :)

The error I was getting upon flash initialization was: **Error calling method on NPObject**

On the JS side, this was the code that broke everything:

```
// attempt to talk to Flash
flash._externalInterfaceTest(false);     <- KABOOM!
```

NPObject errors might have many meanings, but more often than not (in our environment) it means: *You're trying to call the ExternalInterface through JS on a flash movie hosted on a different domain.*

After a while I popped open SoundManager2 ActionScript 3 code and saw this:

```
public var allow_xdomain_scripting:Boolean = false;
public var xdomain:String = "*";

[... other stuff ...]

if (allow_xdomain_scripting && xdomain) {
    Security.allowDomain(xdomain);
    version_as += ' - cross-domain enabled';
}
```

Of course that means that the movie that you might be using (no matter if it's debug or not) will not be accessible from a different domain (a CDN, or whatever).

The solution was –as stated in @amlutz160's answer– **to use the files contained in swf/soundmanager2_flash_xdomain.zip, which are compiled with allow_xdomain_scripting = true**.

Posting this is quite embarrassing, and the solution **is obvious**, but I lost quite a bit of time with this and AFAIK the contents of that mysterious zip file are not documented anywhere (I found a [tangential mention on SM2 forums](https://getsatisfaction.com/schillmania/topics/soundmanager2_and_crossdomain)).

PS: I'm forwarding this answer to [Scott Schiller](https://twitter.com/schill) so maybe he can update SoundManager2 docs a little bit :P

Regards!

Comment: Added support request: 
[Improve documentation regarding cross-domain usage of SM2](https://getsatisfaction.com/schillmania/topics/improve_documentation_regarding_cross_domain_usage_of_sm2)